# Capitalize the string in iphone

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, string, nsstring

I have a date in string format like: 9th march 2013,15th october 2012,etc.

**How can I convert this into like: 9th March 2013, 15th October 2013?**

I done like: `[str capitalizedString]` but it will also capitalize the **T** from th.

Comment: which str you need to capitalize

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik, only first letter of month.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this is your string below. So on the basis of that it will only upper the month in the below date format:-

```
 NSString *str= @"9th march 2013, 15th October 2013";
NSString *str1=[str stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange(0, 5) withString:[[str substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, 5)]uppercaseString]];
NSString *str2=[str1 stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange(0, 3) withString:[[str substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, 3)]lowercaseString]];
NSLog(@"%@",str2);
```

OutPut:-

```
9th March 2013, 15th October 2013
```

Comment: right there is no other way of selecting a range, i was also trying, and ended up with this

Answer (score 0):

If you string format same as above: then you can do it in such a way:

```
NSString *yourString = @"9th march 2013,15th october 2012";
NSArray *array = [yourString componentsSeparatedByString:@","];

NSMutableArray *finalArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

for (int i =0 ; i < [array count]; i++) {

    NSString *innerStr = [array objectAtIndex:i];

    NSArray *newArray = [innerStr componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];

    NSString *monthStr = [newArray objectAtIndex:1];

    monthStr = [[[monthStr substringToIndex:1]uppercaseString]stringByAppendingString:[monthStr substringFromIndex:1]];

    NSString *finalString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@ %@", [newArray objectAtIndex:0],monthStr,[newArray objectAtIndex:2]];

    [finalArray addObject:finalString];
}

NSLog(@"%@",finalArray);
```

You can store final string into `NSString` by loop through to `finalArray`. Or with in above loop itself.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like:

```
- (NSString *)changeMonthToCapital:(NSString *)str
{
    // You need to do proper exception handling
    NSMutableArray *components = [[str componentSeparatedBy:@" "] mutableCopy];
    NSString *newTxt           = [components objectAtIndex:1];
    NSString *changedTxt       = [newTxt stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange(0,1) withString:[[newTxt substringToIndex:1] uppercaseString]];
    [components  replaceObjectAtIndex:1 withObject:changedTxt];
    str = [components  componentsJoinedByString:@" "];
    return str;
}
```

You can call it like:

```
[self changeMonthToCapital:@"9th march 2013"];
```